# How to get full callstack of FaultException

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, callstack

I have a WCF service that throws an exception.

I get a FaultException in the client without an InnerException.

I only have part of the callstack of the original exception, from which it's hard to understand what caused this.

How do I get the original exception or at least all the callstack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a faultexception that you are throwing you could add the callstack, or other information, using the constructor, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.faultexception(v=VS.100).aspx

You also have the "include exception detail in faults" property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx

Comment: I have the details, but not the full callstack and causing exceptions.

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?